# How to draw on X axis in R

Tags: r, charts

VERY new to programming here, I need to draw a chart in R with all the numbers from 1 to 10 showing on the X axis. Right now it shows only the even numbers, and if I try to use `axes=FALSE` and redraw the X axis, it doesn't draw anything. This is the code I am using right now.

```
casi <- c(2102, 2590, 2831, 3235, 3893, 3697, 3151, 3401, 2657)
g_range <- range(0, casi)
plot(casi, type="o", col="red", axes=FALSE, ylim=g_range, xlab="giorni", ylab="casi", main="Casi in Cina Febbraio")
axis(1, at = seq(1, 10, by = 1), las=2)
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get a plot with 1 to 9 on the x-axis (you only have 9 data points... do you want the axis to extend beyond the data?). Try closing the graphics device with `dev.off()` and running your code again.

Comment: I will add the 10th data point today, when I run the code the graph shows no axis at all. Just the graph and the labels.

Where should I put `dev.off()` exactly? I tried to put it in different places but it just doesn't run now.
I'm sorry but as I said I'm really new in this.

Comment: Graphics devices (that is, the actual plotting window) can get into bad states if you run certain commands---especially if you are trying lots of stuff that you don't understand. Entering `dev.off()` in your console turns the graphics device off, so a new one will be created next time you plot. Don't put in in your script file, just run the line in your R console.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the question/problem is. I am getting a perfectly fine plot. If you want 10 to show on the X axis (without a value yet) you can add `xlim = c(1,10)` to your plot call: `plot(casi, type="o", col="red", axes=FALSE, ylim=g_range, xlab="giorni", ylab="casi", main="Casi in Cina Febbraio", xlim = c(1, 10))`

Comment: I don't know what is happening, I'm on windows and I'm running the last version of R, the 3.6.2, but nothing it's changing in the output.
It either doesn't run (a window does appear, but it is all gray), or it run but there the value on the X axis are only 2-4-6-8.

It's like it's not using the line to re-draw the axis.